# mongodb - performance for multiple queries

Tags: mongodb

I've been trying to generate static pages with nextjs faster.
I want to build a product page and that shows a product with reviews and similar products.
Got two collections: ***products*** (12k docs) and ***reviews*** (24k docs).
I have created index via compass, and I've created one for slug in ***products*** and one using url as key in ***reviews***.

I've tried using lookup to fetch reviews for the product but that didnt improve much. So below is the fastest I managed to build.

First I fetch the product with the slug. Then I access the ***reviews*** collection to fetch all reviews connected to the product (dont ask me why they use a wierd key as url). Then 16 related product, the categorySlug is an array with strings that says which type of product it is, and votes and rating is used to find popular ones. These 16 is then sorted random and 4 is selected to return to client. Reason for the ugly JS solution is that when I ran a aggragation and using $sample to select 4 products it was alot slower.

I have no index for the last one since I dont know how to handle index for an string array. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

```
 const product = (await db.collection('products').findOne({
    slug: slug,
  }));

  if (!product) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  const reviews = (await db
    .collection('reviews')
    .find({ url: product.url })
    .project({ _id: 0 })
    .toArray());

  const similar = (await db
    .collection('products')
    .find({
      categorySlug: product.categorySlug,
      rating: { $gte: 4 },
      votes: { $gte: 1 },
    })
    .sort({ rating: -1, votes: -1 })
    .limit(16)
    .toArray());

  return {
    ...product,
    reviews: reviews,
    similar:
    similar.length > 4
      ? similar
          .filter((p) => p.title !== product.title)
          .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
          .slice(0, 4)
      : similar,
  };
```

Comment: I think there is some missing contextual information here such as what is considered 'slow' and how fast you need it to be. Also, importantly, which part is the slowest (which is usually the place to start)? I'm guessing the last operation (for similar items). Two things might help overall. First, create an index for `products` on `{ categorySlug: 1, rating: -1, votes: -1 }`. Secondarily you could consider collapsing all 3 of these operations into a single aggregation pipeline. Doing so would reduce round trips on the network but it's unclear how much of a bottleneck that is at the moment